# My lawn which is/has overgrown needs weeding

Tags: tense, exam-questions

Is it correct to say :

> My lawn which  **is** overgrown needs weeding.

Or it's better to replace *is* with *has* ? We use present perfect to denote that the action which is still going on, in the above sentence the growth is still going on. So isn't it better to use *has* here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each version means something different. This will take a little while to explain.

## All about overgrowing

The verb **overgrow** is a little bit peculiar. Intransitively, **overgrow** just means "grow too much". So, if you say:

> My lawn **has overgrown**.

this means that your lawn *has been growing* for some period of time, and now the grass is too tall. If your lawn has overgrown, then it probably needs mowing, not weeding:

> My lawn, which **has overgrown**, needs mowing.

You can also use **overgrow** transitively, making the plant the object of **overgrow** and making the subject the person who cultivated—"grew"—the plant:

> I **overgrew** my basil plant.

That is, I cultivated my basil plant until it became too large.

Now here is where it becomes tricky and irregular—in a typically English way. Transitively, *overgrow* can also mean that the subject grows **over** something else—such as one or more plants that grow to cover a place—like a lawn. "Over" has more than one sense: it can mean "too much" or it can mean "on top of, covering". (The "too much" sense only occurs as a prefix.) When weeds **overgrow** a lawn, both senses are evoked! So, in the active voice, you could say:

> Weeds **have overgrown my lawn**.

More commonly, though, people use the passive voice for this, or a passive-like construction:

> My lawn **has been overgrown** by weeds.
>   My lawn **is overgrown with weeds**.

These all mean that weeds have grown "all over" the lawn—which is surely too much. The last construction, where **is overgrown** just means the current state of the lawn (not really passive voice), is the most common.

## Conclusion

So, if you say "My lawn is overgrown", you probably mean that the current state of the lawn is that the grass is too tall—the intransitive sense of *overgrow.* But you could also mean that the current state of the lawn is that it is covered, at least partly, by weeds. This meaning is made clearer by adding *with weeds* as in the last example above. In your original sentence, with **is**, the fact that you're saying that the lawn needs weeding suggests clearly enough that you mean the transitive sense: weeds have grown to cover the lawn. The weeds probably don't cover the lawn completely, but they cover way too much of it.

Saying "My lawn, which has overgrown, needs weeding" doesn't make sense, because "has overgrown" unambiguously indicates the intransitive sense: the lawn has grown too tall—not that weeds have overgrown the lawn.

Comment: Good answer, but I'll raise the same question I raised with StoneyB.  Overgrown doesn't relate just to height or growing "over".  It also relates to density, characteristics of maturity (like becoming woody), plants growing into each other (lack of separation, transmission of pests and diseases), one plant outdoing another (supplanting or choking it), etc.  Your answer defines "lawn" as the grass and weeds as something else.  (cont'd)

Comment: But lawn also refers generically to the carpet of mixed short vegetation (grass and weeds), that surrounds your house.  In that context, it isn't weeds overgrowning lawn, it's overgrowth altering the ratio of weeds to grass in the composition of the lawn.  So weeding is how you readjust the mix when the lawn becomes overgrown.

Comment: @fixer1234 My first thought is that the OP mostly needs help understanding the grammatical pressures from established usage of "overgrown" that give the "has" and "is" versions of the sentence their different meanings. Bringing in weed/grass ratio would add undue complexity. But your objection still deserves an answer! I'll let it slosh around in my brain and see if anything comes up.

Comment: @fixer1234 OK, here's what came up. Oddly enough, I wasn't thinking of "lawn" as limited to the grass and excluding the weeds. I was thinking "lawn" more as the place. The word "lawn" (like any word) is flexibly ambiguous: it will "glom on" to whatever you want to point out or imagine in the situation that corresponds passably well to its core meaning of a  faux-savannah kept artificially short and neat by regular, conspicuously time-consuming maintenance ("mowing"). It can refer to the grass exclusive of weeds—"weeds have invaded my lawn!"—or even to the location bereft of any plants as yet—…

Comment: @fixer1234 …"The house is almost up. Now I'm going to put sod into the lawn [referring to the region of uncultivated dirt in front of the house]." IOW, the word "lawn" *points*, as if you pointed with your finger. Did you point at the place or just at the grass or at all the plant life whether grass or weed? A person would reasonably understand you only by considering what you were saying _about_ it. The same applies to "overgrown". What could you be pointing to that answers to notions of "growing over" and/or "growing too much"? Since you think the lawn needs weeding, probably the weeds. ;) …

Comment: @fixer1234 …Having established that, there's no need to form any more-precise interpretation or definition of "lawn". Weeds have been growing out of control in that grassy, often-mown region, they're getting unsightly, they need to go—got it. Does that answer your objection?—"These words swim in a slurry of useful vagueness, where your question about whether 'lawn' includes or excludes the weeds is neither asked nor answered."

Comment: Geez, I thought you'd slosh better than that.  :-)   Where I was going was that, to me, "my lawn has overgrown and needs weeding" could be correct in terms of grammar and definition (and certainly applies to my own lawn).  I didn't want your answer to be biased to a particular usage or misleading by omission. However, that would be a less common usage, it's not like the fate of the world hangs on this nuance, and getting into the weeds of this discussion (sorry, couldn't resist), is probably of limited incremental value to the OP.  So, good enough for government work.

Comment: @fixer1234 Ohhhh. Now I see. I had misunderstood you, but now I see. Since the lawn includes both grass and weeds, the totality of the lawn can overgrow in the intransitive sense, meaning "gettin' shaggy" like an overgrown beard. Yes, you have persuaded me. Your eye for the flexible ambiguity of words has surpassed my own. I think the *main* pressures at work in the sentence operate as explained in my answer, and I mostly want to make the OP attuned to the those _kinds_ of pressures, so I think I won't complicate my answer any further. But if you explain this in your answer, I'll give it a +1.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use *is* overgrown: although it has the form of a past participle we ordinarily use *overgrown* as an adjective, not a verb, and in any case it's not regarded as something which the lawn 'does' but something which 'happens' to the lawn.
2. If you're going to cast this as a relative clause you need to bracket the clause with commas to mark it as non-restrictive:

   > My lawn, which is overgrown, needs weeding.

   Without commas the clause is taken to be restrictive, implying that you have multiple lawns and are restricting your reference to the one which is overgrown.
3. Ordinarily, however, we wouldn't use a relative clause here but a conjunct predicate:

   > My lawn is overgrown and needs weeding.

   In this context the second predicate is understood to supply the consequence of the first.

Comment: Overgrown is also a verb: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overgrown.  In that usage, it seems like "has" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @fixer1234 But *overgrow* as a verb is usually transitive, as when we say that your lawn 'has overgrown' a flowerbed or a path. If what you mean is that your lawn has too many weeds, you could say that the weeds "have overgrown" the lawn or that the lawn "is overgrown with weeds". On the rare occasions when "overgrow" is intransitive it almost always means *become excessively tall or luxuriant*--you might say "My lawn has overgrown, I must mow it"--but in your case you appear to mean that it is not the lawn but the weeds which "have overgrown" in this sense.

Comment: Hmm.  I don't disagree with your comment, but there's also a slightly different perspective.  If you mean "lawn" to refer strictly to the grass content, I agree.  If you use "lawn" to refer to the expanse of relatively short vegetation surrounding your house that is typically as much weeds as grass, then "overgrown" can refer to that entire mess that is a losing battle to maintain.

Comment: @StoneyB Your comment has inspired me to try yet another answer. Yet again, the struggle to answer these seemingly simple questions teaches me something new and unexpected about how English works. We'll see if any of these help the OP see the light.

Comment: @fixer1234 Quite so; but it seems to me that if you say that the entire mess "has overgrown", the natural followup is not "it needs weeding" but "it needs mowing" !

Comment: @BenKovitz I am irresistibly reminded of a Springsteen song . . .

Comment: @StoneyB, you haven't seen my lawn.  Weeding improves the ratio of grass to weeds.  The height is OK.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Either way can be correct.  Overgrown can be an adjective or a verb.

Used as an adjective, with "is", would refer to its current condition.  See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overgrown).

Used as a verb, with "has", would refer to how it got that way.  See [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overgrown).

Either version of the parenthetical phrase, "which is overgrown" or "which has overgrown", should be set off with commas.  But as StoneyB indicates, it can be incorporated directly into the sentence:

> My lawn is overgrown and needs weeding.
>   My lawn has overgrown and needs weeding.

Neither version really addresses the continuing nature of weed growth, so that isn't a determining factor here.

---

The previous portion of this answer was only intended to deal with with the grammar of overgrown as an adjective or a verb, and the associated use of "is" and "has".  The objective wasn't to get into the definition of "overgrown".  The other answers go into good detail on those uses (StoneyB's answer focuses on adjective use and Ben Kovitz's answer focuses on verb use).  There is one missing nuance that is discussed in comments.  I'll add that here just for completeness.

This is based on the perspective of a lawn being the carpet of short vegetation around your house, consisting of some mix of grass and weeds that you mow short enough so that it looks generally green.

As a verb, overgrown is perhaps most commonly used to refer to something that's grown too tall, or one thing growing over another (the cases Ben's answer focuses on).  But overgrown more generally just means grown too much, and there are many ways that can happen.  It can relate to the density of the plants, characteristics of maturity (like becoming woody), plants growing into each other (lack of separation, transmission of pests and diseases), one plant outdoing another (supplanting or choking it), etc.

The last meaning is common with weeds and grass.  The weeds expand sideways more aggressively and replace the grass. So an overgrown lawn can refer to uncontrolled, excessive growth of the mix of vegetation there, which results in a higher proportion of weeds to grass.  In that case, what it needs is weeding.  That would be the meaning of:

> My lawn has overgrown and needs weeding.

This is just another usage that supplements what Ben described in his answer.

Comment: *has overgrown* is maybe technically correct, but it sounds really weird to this US English speaker.  When I hear "My lawn has overgrown", the next thing I expect to hear is what it has overgrown, like "its boundaries."

Comment: @stangdon, that's certainly a usage, but not a requirement.  Overgrown can also mean grown too tall, weeds choking grass, landscaping overgrowing can refer to plants growing into each other, etc.

Comment: @stangdon Are you thinking of "outgrown"?